# How can I use sar to track processor and memory usage?

Tags: cpu-usage, redhat-enterprise-linux, memory-usage

I'm running some load tests on a application hosted on one of my server and I wanted to track the processor and memory usage over a period of time e.g. 30 minutes.

I've read that I can do this with sar.

The following command gives me the processor and memory usage at 5 second intervals, 72 times which brings it about 30 minutes:

```
sar -r -u 5 72
```

If I've understood correctly, sar can log delimited data to a file so that I can import it into Excel and plot some graphs.

How can I do this? I'm interested in two simple values — the processor usage and the memory usage. This would provide enough information for my tests.

I've never dealt with anything like this before and am quite lost. Would anyone of you be able to guide me? Thanks